# Extract a string without a standard start, end position

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract data from a string column. I need to get data similar to 'HFDD20200203300PM' from a string like : 'Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM'

input2 : 'AEM_ARCH_REVIEW_DONE,Atlas,HFDD2020013000,hotfix,web2020janHF,WARM_HF' output2:'HFDD2020013000'

input3:  'Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM' output3: 'HFDD20200203300PM'

For the above examples, the length and position of characters can't be standarardized. So I am unable to use SUBSTRING function.

I tried the following, but no results:

```
select 
'Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM'
  where 'Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM' like substring('''%HFDD%''',1,17)
```

Could someone please throw light on achieving the above output in SQL server?

Comment: What version of sql server? Will be easy with string split function. You CAN use substring by the way with a combination of charindex and length functions.

Comment: Are those the only 3 *formats* ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out if I understand your question right.

```
DECLARE @Desc VARCHAR(250) = 'Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Desc, PATINDEX('%HFDD%', @Desc), 17)
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)='Atlas,WARM_HF,hotfix,web2020janHF,HFDD20200203300PM'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@STR,CHARINDEX('HFDD',@STR),17)